# How to get KinectSensor properties in c# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, kinect

I am following [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973069.aspx) on how to enable the streaming of color images in Kinect.

At the [*Enable Data Streaming*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973072.aspx#CS_Enable_Data_Streaming) they did it like this:

```
if (this.sensor != null)
    {
      this.sensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
      this.sensor.DepthStream.Enable(DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);
      this.sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
      this.sensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.InfraredResolution640x480Fps30);
    }
```

where sensor is a private obj of type `KinectSensor`.

**Problem:** I am unable to use the properties above (`ColorStream`, `DepthStream`,..).

Also, at the [*Enumerate Kinect Sensors*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973072.aspx#CS_Enumerate) I'm unable to use `KinectSensor.KinectSensors` like it's done in the tutorial, since the only options I see are:

1. `KinectSensor.Equals`
2. `KinectSensor.GetDefault`
3. `KinectSensor.ReferenceEquals`

Why is that i cannot see all the references like in MSDN tutorials? Am I missing a Reference? (already using `Microsoft.Kinect` and `Microsoft.Kinect.Fusion`)